# MS Access - "You don't have permission to read [REPORT NAME]", object owner <unknown>

Tags: database, security, ms-access, permissions

A client is receiving a "You don't have permission to read [REPORT NAME]" error message when attempting to launch a report in a MS Access database.  When I go to the “Change Owner” tab under Tools > Security > User Groups and Permissions, the owner is <unknown>.  If I attempt to change the owner, I get a "You don't have permission to change the owner of [REPORT NAME]." error message.

How do I reclaim the object so I can restore its permissions?

Comment: You're using the wrong workgroup file. That's the source of "<unknown>", i.e., the owner is defined in a different workgroup file. If you can't take ownership of the top-level database object, you're likely out of luck without the correct workgroup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a copy of the database from a month ago and importing the inaccessible reports into a blank Access database file.  Then, I imported the remaining database objects from the current copy of the database.  Problem solved.

As far as I know, they have never used MS Access/MDW security on the database, so I suspect it's just a symptom of an old Access database that's ripe for a .NET/SQL Server migration.